# For loop under With statement not working correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get some sample lines from a file, and this is my approach

```
import gzip, random

random_set = []
with gzip.open('/home/qsnake/Downloads/bigfile.txt.gz') as f:
    lc = sum(1 for x in f)
    random_set += random.sample(xrange(lc), 3)
    for i, x in enumerate(f):
        if i in random_set:
            print "First loop", str(i)
            break

with gzip.open('/home/qsnake/Downloads/biggfile.txt.gz') as f:
    for i, x in enumerate(f):
        if i in random_set:
            print "Second loop", str(i)
            break
```

Here is the result

```
Second loop 4
```

I don't know why the for loop in the first With statement not working, if I remove

```
lc = sum(1 for x in f)
```

It works again.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already read the file once when you have this line in the code:

```
lc = sum(1 for x in f)
```

Now, when you try to `enumerate` on the file again, the pointer is at the end of the file and hence can not read anything.

If you want to read the file again from start in the same with condition, you can set the pointer to 0 before `enumerate`:

```
f.seek(0)
```

Comment: Wow, indeed, my bad I should read more about with statement. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help. Please also read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @QSnake this is not a property of `with`, but of the `open`-ed file object